# Flag flying dynamics

Tags: united-states, law, flags, tradition, vermont

How many flags are allowed to be on one pole?

Is a flag ever flown up side down at half-mast, more than 1 and why?

Comment: When and where? The 'rules' aren't fixed around the world.

Comment: The rules differ by country.  Perhaps you could edit your question to explain what is missing from, or incomplete about, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-mast)

Comment: @sempaiscuba is this better?

Comment: @Muze You still don't say _where_ you are asking about.  Your profile page says you are in Vermont, so your first question may be answered by (for example) [this page](http://www.ushistory.org/betsy/faq2.htm) from USHistory.org

Comment: Is this about history?

Comment: This is a question about laws and customs (which may of course vary by locality).  It has nothing to do with the dynamics of flags, which would be an appropriate question for the Physics site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flag is flown at half-mast in memoriam *as long as deemed appropriate* by the head-of-state of the sovereignty.  Note that in U.S. state governors are deemed to be sovereign within their states in this regard. (*The precise delineation between Gubernatorial and Presidential authority in this regard is a Constitutional Law issue on which SCOTUS hasn't ruled on yet (to the best of my knowledge).*)

For the death of a particularly important personage of a sovereignty it is traditional to fly the flag at half-mast until internment. This was, for example if perhaps reluctantly, the case for the [death last summer of John McCain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCain#Reaction_from_the_White_House).

> President Trump belatedly issued a statement praising McCain's service to the country, and signed a proclamation ordering flags to be flown at half-staff until McCain's interment

In both [Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/canadian-heritage/services/flag-canada-etiquette/flying-rules.html) and [the U.S.](http://www.usaflagsupply.com/upside-down-flag/) protocol is that a flag is flown upside down only as a signal of extreme distress; otherwise doing so is regarded as desecration.

Comment: @Muze: "**distress**; not *disgrace*. It's is a call for aid due to dire life-threatening circumstances.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens "_U.S. state governors are deemed to be sovereign within their states in this regard_" - does that also hold true for flags flying over Federal institutions (e.g. FBI offices) located in those states?

Comment: @sempaiscuba: That is a Constitutional Law issue on which SCOTUS hasn't ruled on yet (to the best of my knowledge). Might make for a good question on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PieterGeerkens,  I disagree.   Flying the flag upside down is not always seen as desecration.  Sometimes it's seen as supreme stupidity.  [Take the 1992 World Series](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/national/flag-flap/article12901837/)

Comment: @JMS: We Canadians have learned to be pleasantly surprised when you get things right in regards Canada- not disappointed when you get it wrong.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm not sure that SCOTUS needs to be consulted.  My understanding is that (since 1923) the rules have been established by the [US Flag Code](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCODE-2011-title4/html/USCODE-2011-title4-chap1.htm) (as amended), and also (since 1954) by Eisenhower's [Proclamation 3044](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/codification/proclamations/03044.html) which sets specific times for different officials.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens,  I remember watching that game and seeing the Canadian flag upside down,  First World Series featuring a Canadian team, and just covering my eyes... how embarrassing, was that.

Comment: I watched that at my 15th Uni reunion; and we all just shook our heads saying "Really! The Marines too." Too be honest I suspect it was a prank gone wrong by Canadians too embarassed afterwards to own up. If so, I admire the Marines for not tattling.

Comment: @JMS: That recounting of memory is nicely written, but also a very nice example of how unreliable eye witness accounts are... "We line up and get ready to march out. Then we hear this announcement..." -- when [the video of the event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77Ar7x6NKMA) clearly shows that the color guards were already positioned on the field when the announcement was made. Not much of an issue, but a good reminder not to blindly trust someone telling you "but I was there!". ;-)

Comment: One addition perhaps, flying two flags at one pole, one above the other, is usually only done with the flag of a subordinated entity as the lower one. Flying the flag of a sovereign nation under your own is usually only done to indicate victory in war.